# Flex: Is there any way to find find out when a ComboBox is open?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I may be missing something here because I thought this might be really easy but...

Using Flex, how can you tell when a ComboBox is open?  I do find the open and close events that this component dispatches can be flaky so I'm looking for something a little more solid - it's probably staring me in the face.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about checking either the existence or the visibility of the dropDown component?

The dropDown is a component of type ListBase, and can be accessed through the `dropDown` property. So maybe something like this (I didn't have time to test this myself):

```
if (myComboBox.dropDown != null && myComboBox.dropDown.visible) {
    // myComboBox is open
}
```

The `myComboBox.dropDown != null` is a safety check so you will not get runtime errors trying to access the `visible` property of a null object.

Answer (score 0):

The designers probably thought it was enough with the open and close events.

EDIT: I'll clarify that. Looking for a property that would reveal the opened/closed status of the combobox I fail to find it. And to my experience there's nothing flaky about the event system.

Comment: Maybe I need to clarify - the event system isn't flaky, but the close event that is supposed to be broadcast whenever the combobox is closed does not dispatch in every situation.

Comment: Well, that's flaky =) And a bit strange.